# I cast doubt on the theorem about function's measurability of semi-continuous function.

Tags: measure-theory

Def) $f$ is measurable if, for all $a$ in $\mathbb{R^1}$,
 $$\left\{\mathbf{x}:f(\mathbf{x})\gt a\right\} \text{ is measurable}~.$$

Def) $f$ is said to be upper-semi continuous if $$\limsup_{\mathbf{x}\to \mathbf{x_0}} f(\mathbf{x}) \le f(\mathbf{x_0})~.$$

Def) $f$ is said to be lower-semi continuous if $$\liminf_{\mathbf{x}\to \mathbf{x_0}} f(\mathbf{x}) \le f(\mathbf{x_0})~.$$

Theorem) if a function $f$ is upper- or lower-semi continuous, then $f$ is measurable.

---

I think the following function is not upper- or lower-semi continuous.
\begin{align}f(x)=\begin{cases}0 &x<0 \\1 &x>0\\ 0.5 &x=0\end{cases}\end{align}

However, I think

1. for $a \lt 0$, $\left\{\mathbf{x}:f(\mathbf{x})\gt a\right\}=\mathbb{R^1}$ is measurable, since it is open.
2. for $0 \le a \lt 0.5$, $\left\{\mathbf{x}:f(\mathbf{x})\gt a\right\}=\left[0, +\infty\right)$ is measurable, since it is closed.
3. for $0.5 \le a \lt 1$, $\left\{\mathbf{x}:f(\mathbf{x})\gt a\right\}=\left(0, +\infty\right)$ is measurable, since it is open.
4. for $a \ge 1$, $\left\{\mathbf{x}:f(\mathbf{x})\gt a\right\}=\emptyset$ is measurable, since $\emptyset$ has outer measure $0$.

Therefore,  $f$ is measurable.

Comment: ??? The theorem says any semicontinuous function is measurable. It does not say any measurable function is semicontinuous...

Comment: ...Ah..... it is not if and only if.... Thank you... I posted a stupid question. :( Thank you